# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/util/namespace' is not defined by "exports"

Tags: node.js, jhipster

When I enter jhipster in the cmd command, I get an error Package subpath './lib/util/namespace' is not defined by "exports" in C:Program Filesnodejsnode_globalnode_modulesgenerator-jhipsternode_modules yeoman-environmentpackage.json。I hope someone helps me, thanks

I tried typing npm update

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

there is a bug of Jhipster with new version of NodeJS
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/19627